# DLib build on Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, dlib

I am trying to build dlib18.18. I run the following commands on terminal

```
cd examples
cd build
make -G Xcode ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

but I get these errors on below after a while

> /Users/gyillikci/Downloads/dlib-18.18/dlib/../dlib/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.h:11:2: error: "DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT is defined so you can't use the GUI code. Turn
>         DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT off if you want to use it."
>   #error "DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT is defined so you can't use the GUI code.  T...
>    ^
>   /Users/gyillikci/Downloads/dlib-18.18/dlib/../dlib/gui_core/gui_core_kernel_2.h:12:2: error: 
>         "Also make sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system"
>   #error "Also make sure you have libx11-dev installed on your system"
>    ^
>   2 errors generated.

How can I overcome DLIB_NO_GUI_SUPPORT and libx11-dev problems.

Comment: Have you installed XQuartz on your Mac?

Comment: After your comment, I have tried it but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: I've also just noticed that your compile commands are not what the compiling instructions on the Dlib website say. Your `make -G Xcode ..` should be `cmake -G Xcode ..`. In addition, I'm not sure you need the `-G Xcode` part, just try `cmake ..`. Finally, after you install XQuartz, when you re-build Dlib, make sure the build directory is empty before you run the `cmake` commands. I have a Macbook Pro Retina 13' (the latest one at the time of this writing) and everything worked fine for me.

Comment: @Ray You were write i managed to compile Dlib Thanks